# Access my stuff on a second harddrive from another computer

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, sata

Alright, I can't seem to find a good solution to this problem (and I can't quite get my Google search terms right either).  I've taken a HD from my old XP computer and plugged it into my computer via the SATA.  Online, I've found that many people had to format their HD to get it to work, but I kind of need the data that's on it.

**Here's what I hope to accomplish:**

Be able to set it up with a virtual machine to simply run my old XP box in a virtual machine.

**Here is what I'll settle with:**

Be able to access the data from my default OS and be able to use it as a second HD.

Does anybody know the best way to go about this?  I would prefer the first option, but the second would be fine as a last case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to format it. It should just work as a secondary drive

Now, i've found in some cases, where windows can't read a hard drive, and insists it needs to format, the linux NTFS-3G driver will work.

Running it as a VM is a little trickier. In an ideal world, you'd probably run systprep or some p2v tool on the running system. You could probably mount the hard drive as a raw device in your VM software, run a live p2v tool of some sort and convert it if it dosen't work. Alternately boot up the xp system on the old system and run sysprep, or run some cloning tool that allows migration to dissimilar hardware.